# Can't use imported object in Vue props validator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a `validator` function for a Vue component's prop.

The `validator` function requires an imported object to do the validation, however, when the `validator` function is run, the imported object is `undefined`.

Once the component has been mounted, the imported object **is** defined *(so there isn't a problem with the import syntax)*.

My component's Javascript code is as follows:

```
<script>
    import {EventTypes, PageTypes, logger} from "../core/EventLogger";
    import FAQ from "./FAQ";
    export default {
        name: "MobilityFAQs",
        components: {
            FAQ
        },
        props: {
            faqs: {
                required: true,
                type: Array
            },
            pageType: {
                required: true,
                validator: value => {
                    return value in PageTypes
                    // PageTypes is undefined here.
                }
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(PageTypes);
            // PageTypes is defined here.
        }
    }
</script>
```

The same issue occurs with different function definition syntax:

```
validator: function(value) {
    return value in PageTypes
}
```

There is a warning in the documentation that you will not be able to access instance properties in the `validator` function, as expected, but this is not an instance property.

> Note that props are validated before a component instance is created, so instance properties (e.g. data, computed, etc) will not be available inside default or validator functions.

How can I use the imported object in the `validator` function?

---

**Update following Jacobs answer:**

I was incorrectly using Javascript's `in` operator.

My updated `validator` function is now:

```
validator: value => Object.values(PageTypes).includes(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

(Just a guess.. will delete if it's not true)

`PageTypes` is actually defined, but you are using `in` operator incorrectly. That's why the validation fails.

`value in PageTypes` check if is `value` is a key/property in `PageTypes`. It's the same as `PageTypes.hasOwnProperty(value)`.

What you actually want to do might be checking the object value, not the object key. If so, use `Object.values(PageTypes).includes(value)`

Comment: Nice spot - I'm too used to Python! I've updated my answer with the change. Thanks Jacob